# How to iterate over dict sorted by element in subdict?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

How to iterate over dict sorted by element in subdict?
For example I have dict of subdicts and want to get output
sorted by TEMP item in subdict?

Input values:

```
d={ 'Kitchen':{'Light':22, 'Temp':23, 'Power':0},
    'Garage':{'Light':0, 'Temp':10, 'Power':5},
    'LivingRoom':{'Light':0, 'Temp':21, 'Power':120},
}
```

Something like that

```
for i in sorted(d):
    print (i,d[i])
```

Should provide that result:

```
'Garage':{'Light':0, 'Temp':10, 'Power':5},
'LivingRoom':{'Light':0, 'Temp':21, 'Power':120},
'Kitchen':{'Light':22, 'Temp':23, 'Power':0},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a custom `lambda` function as a sorting criterion using the `key` argument of the `sorted` function:

```
for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key = lambda i : i[1]['Temp']):
    print(k, v)
```

Output:

```
Garage {'Light': 0, 'Temp': 10, 'Power': 5}
LivingRoom {'Light': 0, 'Temp': 21, 'Power': 120}
Kitchen {'Light': 22, 'Temp': 23, 'Power': 0}
```

Another approach using only the keys and then fetching the values later:

```
for k in sorted(d, key = lambda k : d[k]['Temp']):
    print(k, d[k])
```

Output:

```
Garage {'Light': 0, 'Temp': 10, 'Power': 5}
LivingRoom {'Light': 0, 'Temp': 21, 'Power': 120}
Kitchen {'Light': 22, 'Temp': 23, 'Power': 0}
```